# BoxWhiskerChart Two Sets of Data

Tags: charts

I have researched and looked at examples given within the Mathematica Documentation but I cant seen to accomplish what Im trying to do.

I have to sets of data sets

```
  set1 = {5,10,15,20};

  set2= {7,12,45,45};
```

I want to display them right next to each other in the same box/chart.

If I do this for each individually it works but I dont want them displayed seperately.

```
  BoxWhisketChart[{set1},ChartLabels->{"Example 1"}]
  BoxWhisketChart[{set2},ChartLabels->{"Example 2"}]
```

However, It does not if I do it together

```
  BoxWhisketChart[{set1},{set2},ChartLabels->{"Example 1"}ChartLabels->
  {"Example 2"}]
```

I've looked at examples but none offer the correct result. What Can I do for this to work? Or is it even possible?

Comment: Try giving [`BoxWhiskerChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxWhiskerChart.html) your data as `{set1, set2}`. Did you check the examples in the `ChartLabels` option?

Comment: @Anne Thank you so much! That worked. Honestly I thought I had tried that but It worked. I had been looking for 3 hours.